# MongoDB query for adding to array if not present

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am new to MongoDB and want to know if there is any way to add an embedded document **to an array if it is not present.**

Let's say I have a collection called `products`:

```
{
    _id: "123",
    name: "Hair-Dryer",
    locations: [{
            code: "MA",
            name: "Massachusetts"
        },
        {
            code: "IL",
            name: "illinois"
        }
    ]
}, {
    _id: "456",
    name: "Toaster",
    locations: [{
        code: "MA",
        name: "Massachusetts"
    }, ]
}
```

Now lets say I want to add :

```
{
        code: "IL",
        name: "illinois"
}
```

To only those documents which don't have them. **Note that, I don't know which documents have my required data or which don't have them.** I need to find that out.

How can I write a query like this in MongoDB ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) operator adds a value to an array unless the value is already present, in which case $addToSet does nothing to that array.

Try this:

```js
db.locations.updateMany({}, {
    $addToSet: {
        locations: {
            code: "IL",
            name: "illinois"
        }
    }
});
```